# Blue close vote count wraps to two lines

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I've got this issue on ruSO, but it probably happens on all SE sites. When closing a question as a duplicate, the number of votes already given for the same question wraps to two lines. As far as I see it depends on the length of the original question's title.

> [image: close as duplicate]

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Nightly 96.0a1. Can be fixed by using `display: inline-block;`, but there’s probably a more robust Grid or Flex solution.